# Captcha image not loaded in YII 2.0 backend

Tags: php, yii2, captcha, backend

I am just new to yii 2.0 framework. I have setup yii2.0 advanced application. I am trying to implement captcha on backend. Someone give me help to see files of contact page in framework of below files :

1. @frontend/controllers/SiteController.php
   especially "actions()" method and "actionContact()" method.
2. `@frontend/models/ContactForm.php`
3. `@frontend/views/site/contact.php`

So i have copied follwing code in below file :

1. `@backend/views/sitelogin.php`

   ```
   <?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode')
          ->widget(Captcha::className(), [
          'template' => '<div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-3">{image}</div>
             <div class="col-lg-6">{input}</div></div>',
        ]);
   ?>
   ```
2. `@common/models/adminlogin.php`

   ```
   extend model class public $verifyCode;
   ```

   than declare in public function rules()

   ```
   ['verifyCode', 'captcha'],
   ```

and

```
public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'verifyCode' => 'Verification Code',
        ];
    }
```

3. `@backend/controllers/sitecontroller.php` 
   declare below function

   ```
     'captcha' => [
               'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
               'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
           ],
   ```

now the issue is captcha appear on login page but iamge of captcha is not appearing it even prompt me error to enter captcha but no captcha image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In the backend/site/login.php 
 replace:

```
<?= 
    $form->field($model, 'verifyCode')->widget(Captcha::className(), [
    'template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3">{image}</div><div class="col-lg-6">{input}</div></div>',]) 
?>
```

With:

```
<?php 
    $tag = $form->field($model, 'verifyCode')->widget(Captcha::className(), [
                'template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3">{image}</div><div class="col-lg-6">{input}</div></div>',]); 
    $tag = preg_replace('/backend/', 'frontend', $tag); 
    echo $tag;
?>
```

Comment: Well it haven't helped. Anyhow I have fixed this myself.